# Display website icon in mobile web-search results

Tags: html, favicon

In the figure below each search result has a card that then has the website logo for it in the upper right hand corner. This is on Chrome for Android.
[image: Mobile search on Google for 'Facebook' using Chrome for Android]

Some research has led me to believe that this is the `favicon` for the website and I've included it in my HTML using this [favicon generator](http://faviconit.com/en). I've included just the icon aspect of header tag in my current `index.html` that has been deployed.

```
    <!--Link address bar icon file for any browser-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./images/favicons/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32 64x64" href="./images/favicons/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="196x196" href="./images/favicons/favicon-192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="160x160" href="./images/favicons/favicon-160.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="./images/favicons/favicon-96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="64x64" href="./images/favicons/favicon-64.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicons/favicon-32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./images/favicons/favicon-16.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./images/favicons/favicon-57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="./images/favicons/favicon-114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="./images/favicons/favicon-72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="./images/favicons/favicon-144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="./images/favicons/favicon-60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="./images/favicons/favicon-120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="./images/favicons/favicon-76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="./images/favicons/favicon-152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="./images/favicons/favicon-180.png">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="./images/favicons/favicon-144.png">
    <meta name="msapplication-config" content="./images/favicons/browserconfig.xml">
```

My current deployment service is [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/).My problem is that even though I've done this, the website pops up in search results but not the logo. How do I get the website logo to show up in search results?

Comment: what search engine is that ?

Comment: @johnSmith Google

Comment: i´m nearly 100% sure it´s about your links `./` use absolute links without the `.` so `href="/images/...`

Comment: You might want to use https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker to check your paths, favicon.ico format, etc. Full disclosure: I'm the author of this service.

Comment: @philippe_b Hi, I've been successful with getting the icon to show after using your service. Can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @johnSmith Sorry, even after using the absolute links there was no change. I think the main issue was there not being a favicon.ico in the root directory as the service from philippe_b pointed out.

Comment: @S.Ramjit I'm glad the service was helpful! I've just submitted an answer. Thank you for suggesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try to the [favicon checker](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker), which reports broken links, ill-formed images, etc. Full disclosure: I'm the author of this service.